# The date format issue from java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I get the date format from a joynet cloud api server:

```
2012-11-20T10:26:04+00:00"
```

However, I have no idea to handle the last segment **+00:00**, I have made the format except for +00:00

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fmt.parse("2012-11-20T10:26:04");
```

---

Thanks for @Abu

I rewrite it to remove ":",

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String input = "2012-11-20T10:25:58+00:00";

String s1 = input.split("T")[0];
String s2 = input.split("T")[1];
String sep = null;
if (s2.contains("+")) {
    sep = "+";
}
if (s2.contains("-")) {
    sep = "-";
}
String s3 = s2.split("\\" + sep)[0];
String s4 = s2.split("\\" + sep)[1].replace(":", "");
String cleanDate = s1 + "T" + s3 + sep + s4;
Date date = fmt.parse(cleanDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove that `:` inside the time zone part if you are not using java 7

and use this :

`SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");`

See javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

And

If you are using Java 7 then directly use this :

`SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");`

See javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)